# Arc Map 10.2.2 crashes with execution of buffer/Arc tool box

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox

I have been trying to get simple buffer zone around a polygon shape with 50m distance but after entering data ArcMap 10.2.2 suddenly crashes without any warning.Tried repairing and reinstalling software, but nothing seems work. Not only the buffer, I guess My Arc toolbox is not working, because I tried to use near, multiple buffer ring too and nothing works.

Comment: You do not give enough details but wild guess is that your data are in WGS84 latitude-longitude degrees and you tried to create a buffer of 50 degrees, not 50 meters.

Comment: its in meter coordinate system i.e. TM Sri Lanka 95

Comment: Since the software itself is capable of doing this, the question becomes one about your specific installation. You haven't provided enough information to troubleshoot a corrupt installation.

Comment: Try contacting ESRI support

Comment: Thanks all !!! I have tried creating new default database since I have seen in some thread in here saying that it works for them. but didn't work for me. I'm using 10.2.2 version, when installing I've put 3D engine (not ARC INFO) as feature in KeyGen window , is that the problem?